# How to use new grouped together values in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I have combine different values which means the same, under the variable "Wine_type"

```
 Mock     Neg Neg1PCR  NegPBS     red     Red RedWine   water   Water   white   White 
  1       9       1       1       2      18       4       3       4       2      24
```

into

```
Mock       Neg   Neg1PCR    NegPBS   Redwine     Water Whitewine 
    1         9         1         1        24         7        26
```

By using this code

```
dat2<- data.frame(sample_data(psdata.r), stringsAsFactors =FALSE )
dat2$Project<- as.character(dat2$Wine_type)
table(dat2$Project)
dat2[grepl("water|water", dat2$Project, ignore.case = TRUE), "Project"] <- "Water"

dat2[grepl("White|white", dat2$Project, ignore.case = TRUE), "Project"] <- "Whitewine"

dat2[grepl("red|Red", dat2$Project, ignore.case = TRUE), "Project"] <- "Red"

dat2[grepl("Red|Redwine", dat2$Project, ignore.case = TRUE), "Project"] <- "Redwine"
```

then i produce a plot by the code

```
   plot_richness(psdata.r, measures = c("Observed","Shannon"), x = "Wine_type", color = "SampleType") + geom_boxplot()
```

the only problem is that i get a plot with the old values. What am i missing to use the new group together values?

Comment: You are changing dat2 dataframe , but you are displaying GlobalPatterns.

Comment: After edits, you are modifying a data frame named `dat2`, and then plotting a different data frame named `psdata.r`. You need to plot the same data that you modify.

Comment: A mistake i missed when i paste it to here,but In the original run i ran psdata.r. I have fixed it in the code.

Comment: i get a error"Error in .local(object, taxa_are_rows) : 
  argument "taxa_are_rows" is missing, with no default"